# Displaying Application insights and analytics graphs and charts from Azure to a Web Application Dashboard Page

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-lake

I am trying to display application insights and analytics in a web application dashboard page. Is there a way to fetch and display for example number of users as shown in the picture with the graph on a web application dashboard page from Azure portal? [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EWZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in an "azure dashboard" ? if so, then the screenshot you are showing has a pin icon right above the chart, that would pin that view in the screenshot to an azure dashboard.

#### other options:

the queries that chart uses are available by pressing the logs button in the toolbar right above the chart.

- you can use that query in the logs view and pin that result to an azure dashboard.
- you can use that query in the azure workbooks view and pin that result to an azure dashboard
- If you are trying to do this in some other kind of application/dashboarding tool, you could use the [application insights /query REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query) to run that query (or any query) and show the results anywhere you want.

Comment: I want to display those charts and graphs on my web application dashboard page not on Azure dashboard. I am trying to fetch that data so i can display it on the web application

Comment: As @john-gardner pointed out, just use the REST API to fetch the data.